# Sow and Reap returning different results for the same expression

Tags: sow-reap

Consider the following trivial example:

```
{Sow[1]; 2; Sow[3]; 4; 5} // (Reap /* Last)
(* Output: {} *)

{Sow[1]; 2; Sow[3]; 4; 5} // Reap // Last
(* Output: {{1, 3}} *)
```

Moreoever, if I first build an expression containing `Sow` and then `Reap` it, I get an empty list both times:

```
ClearAll[expr];
expr = {Sow[1]; 2; Sow[3]; 4; 5};

expr // (Reap /* Last)
(* Output: {} *)

expr // Reap // Last
(* Output: {} *)
```

What is the reason for this anomalous behaviour?

Comment: `Reap` must hold the code inside. The postfix function application operator `//` does not affect that, but the composition operator does - since it does not hold the arguments in intermediate function applications. Try `Composition[Hold, Hold][Print[1]]` and you will see that `1` gets printed. You would need a holding version of `Composition` (or `RightComposition`) for this to work.

Comment: What makes you think they are "the same expression"?

Comment: @ciao In this case there may be some special syntactical rules at play, which Leonid Shifrin explains in his comment above. But I think the onus would be on anyone claiming that the resulting expressions are not the same to explain why that is so. Within the "normal" rules of Wolfram Language, it is perfectly reasonable to assume that the expressions are the same.

Comment: @Shredderroy The expressions are certainly not the same, since `Composition` or `RightComposition` are separate functions, which prompt chained function application as a result of evaluation of expression,  while `//` is just another syntax for function application, which is resolved at parse time, not evaluation time - so for all intents and purposes is equivalent to just `func[expr]` (one just need to  pay attention to precedence). Wrap each expression    in `Hold` and inspect the `FullForm` of the results, to see the difference.

Comment: Actually, on closer scrutiny, I now understand why the expressions are not the same. My apologies to @ciao. And thanks to Leonid Shifrin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You play a syntax puzzle.  In order to see what is going on:

```
{Sow[1]; 2; Sow[3]; 4; 5} // (Reap1 /* Last1)
(* Last1[Reap1[{5}]] *)
```

The Last of a Reap that sows nothing is obviously the empty list.

```
{Sow[1]; 2; Sow[3]; 4; 5} // Reap // Last1
Last1[{{5}, {{1, 3}}}]
```